# How to preserve images and styling in PDF when creating a searchable PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, ocr, tesseract

I have a website where my clients can upload their files (mainly PDFs). I want to be able to make the PDF searchable but I do not want the look and feel of the PDF to be changed. I have tried creating a .NET endpoint to achieve this that I can POST to.

I have tried iTextSharp in conjunction with Tesseract but neither of them are giving me what I am looking for. Here is the code that I have tried:

Using tesseract to get the text from the pdf:

```
     using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
     using (var img = Pix.LoadFromFile(testImagePath))
     using (var page = engine.Process(img))
     {
        var text = page.GetText();
     }
```

then using iTextSharp to generate the PDF from the old one:

```
// open the reader
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldFile);
Rectangle size = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1);
Document document = new Document(size);

// open the writer
FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
document.Open();

// the pdf content
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;

// select the font properties
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252,BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.DARK_GRAY);
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8);

// write the text in the pdf content
cb.BeginText();
string text = "Some random blablablabla...";
// put the alignment and coordinates here
cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 520, 640, 0);
cb.EndText();
cb.BeginText();
text = "Other random blabla...";
// put the alignment and coordinates here
cb.ShowTextAligned(2, text, 100, 200, 0);
cb.EndText();

// create the new page and add it to the pdf
PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1);
cb.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);

// close the streams and voilá the file should be changed :)
document.Close();
fs.Close();
writer.Close();
reader.Close();
```

I am having issues generating the desired output however. Is there a simpler way to achieve what I am looking for? Here is an example of a PDF I am trying to make searchable. I do not want to lose the images or the font / styling of the PDF. I just want it to become searchable:

https://www.fujitsu.com/global/Images/sv600_c_normal.pdf

Comment: I have added the `itext` tag to your question. As I commented under your other question, iText Software may be able to help you. BUT that goes beyond what can be done here on Stack Overflow, so I suggest that you contact the company directly.

Comment: Oh and you can also get a free 30 day trial of iText 7 + pdfOCR. More at https://itextpdf.com/en/products/itext-7/pdf-ocr-text-recognition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're interested in leveraging a commercial product for this, the [LEADTOOLS SDK](https://www.leadtools.com) has an OCR toolkit with [image-over-text functionality](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v21/dh/ft/pdfdocumentoptions-imageovertext.html).  This feature sets an image of the original file as an overlay in the output PDF, both making the text searchable and maintaining the appearance of the original input file.

I was able to convert your document to a searchable version still representing the original using this code:

```
     string folderPath = "filepath";

     string inputFilename = Path.Combine(folderPath, "sv600_c_normal.pdf");
     string outputFilename = Path.Combine(folderPath, "sv600_c_normal-output.pdf");

     IOcrEngine engine = OcrEngineManager.CreateEngine(OcrEngineType.LEAD);
     engine.Startup(null, null, null, null);

     PdfDocumentOptions pdfOptions = engine.DocumentWriterInstance.GetOptions(DocumentFormat.Pdf) as PdfDocumentOptions;
     pdfOptions.ImageOverText = true;
     engine.DocumentWriterInstance.SetOptions(DocumentFormat.Pdf, pdfOptions);

     engine.AutoRecognizeManager.Run(inputFilename, outputFilename, DocumentFormat.Pdf, null, null);
```

Here's the [output](https://gofile.io/d/MRYwKW) of the sample file.  It's searchable and resembles the original.

Disclaimer:  I work for this company

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Is this available as a Nuget package? Is this free use or a commercial library?

Comment: This functionality is included in the [Leadtools.Ocr](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads/nuget?nuget_package=Leadtools.Ocr) NuGet package.  Note while this is a commercial library, it is available for a 60-day evaluation at no cost.  Usage beyond the evaluation period requires a purchase.